# Clear push notification registrations on Worklight server

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am looking to clear all the push notification registrations on my Enterprise Edition Worklight Server v5.0.5 deployed on WAS 8.5. 
We have one user, with just two devices, but the WL console push notifications display 6 registered devices for that user. Seems like some of the registrations have duplicated themselves, or have become corrupted. One of the devices no longer receives push notification messages, which used to work before.
I tried deleting the adapter that declares the event source, and even re-deploying the application. However, the push notification registrations are still intact when the adapter is re-deployed. Could you please let me know how to clear these entries from the WL server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only way to do so would be to clear the contents of the tables in the database.
The specific tables in this instance would be:

NOTIFICATION_DEVICE and
NOTIFICATION_USER

If it is OK from you to also re-deploy the application, then before doing so also clear these two:

NOTIFICATION_APPLICATION and
NOTIFICATION_MEDIATOR

Comment: Thank you Idan. This works for us after we cleared all the four tables and re-deployed the application & adapter. This should be reported as a possible bug to be fixed, since it seems to be a regular issue with notification registrations getting corrupt/duplicated. I have seen the same issue in development environment, where I need to clear the project server folder under WorklightServer in order for it to work.

Comment: Denzil, will look into it. Until then, if this question is answered, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I subscribed two devices for Push and later i unsubscribed one device. But when sending Push, it comes to both devices. Any idea or suggestion , please. thanks

Comment: @IdanAdar - What table names we need to clean in version 6.2.0 ?